# How to make a highscore value for each level in a game in Game Center leaderboards?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm making a game, where each level has scores. Now, I am adding Game Center leaderboards. But there is a problem, I want Game Center to show high scores for each, not one high score value. For instance: I have 60 levels, so when you go to game center leaderboards you will see a levels table, you choose needed level to see the highest score in this level. Is this possible?

Comment: I can't try now, but can you try if [groupidentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkleaderboard/1503135-groupidentifier) solve the problem? 
I'm interested

Comment: couldn't you just create a leaderboard for each level?